# Adobe Illustrator Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe

I'm Trying to install adobe illustrator CC2017 from https://github.com/Gictorbit/illustratorCClinux
and got this problem, what should i do?
[Error at wine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfgfT.png)

Comment: version and distro of ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `wine` and `md5sum` in your system first

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable7
```

Ubuntu has included `md5sum` in their distro for several years.